# ODBC Select all command

Tags: asp.net, mysql, odbc

The following code works fine when the limit is 0,1 when I limit them to 0,30 I cannot retrieve records I am sure that my database has enough number of records.
But I doubt the syntax after dr[3].ToString(); How to retrieve all of them.

```
string MyConString = "DRIVER={MySQL ODBC 3.51 Driver};" + "SERVER=localhost;" + "DATABASE=malla_softmail2;" + "UID=xxx;" + "PASSWORD=xxx;" + "OPTION=3";
        OdbcConnection MyConnection = new OdbcConnection(MyConString);
        MyConnection.Open();
        OdbcCommand cmd = new OdbcCommand("Select * from awm_test where user=? limit= 0, 1", MyConnection);
        cmd.Parameters.Add("@email", OdbcType.VarChar, 255).Value = "hello";
        OdbcDataReader dr = cmd.ExecuteReader();
        if (dr.HasRows == false)
        {
          //  throw new Exception();
        }
        if (dr.Read())
        {
            string a = dr[0].ToString();
            string b = dr[1].ToString();
            string c = dr[2].ToString();
            //string d = dr[3].ToString();
            //string f = dr[4].ToString();
            //string g = dr[5].ToString();

            Response.Write(a);
            Response.Write(b);
            Response.Write(c);
            //Response.Write(d);
            //Response.Write(f);
            //Response.Write(g);
```

Comment: My requirement is to setup a simple "users search" page to browse the database values.

Comment: are you sure that you have "hello" more than once in your table ?

Comment: NOTE - There are 3 fields in each record...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You're only processing the first record returned by your query. Try:

```
while (dr.Read()) {
    string firstField = dr[0].ToString();
    string secondField = dr[1].ToString();
    string thirdField = dr[2].ToString();

    // ...
}
```

Comment: this can retrieve only the first record. I have 3 fields in each record

Comment: @Karthik, it will process all the records since `Read()` is called in a `while` loop (assuming, of course, you increase or remove your `LIMIT` clause).

Answer (score 0):

You just need to read the rows in a loop with `while(dr.Read()) {...do stuff for each row...}` - each `dr.Read()` moves to the next row.